# Load values from dynamically created TextBoxes, ASPx

Tags: c#, asp.net

on my aspx i have

```
 <div id ="div1" runat="server"></div>
 <div id ="div2" runat="server"></div>
```

etc.

and code behind creates textboxes in those divisors like so

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
      Control ctrl = FindControlRecursive(Page, string.Format("div{0}", i));
      System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl ctrl2 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)ctrl;
      TextBox tbt = new TextBox();
       tbt.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Title");
       tbt.ID = string.Format("page{0}", i);
       ctrl2.Controls.Add(tbt);
       ctrl2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  "));
       TextBox tbu = new TextBox();
       tbu.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "URL");
       tbu.ID = string.Format("page{0}url", i);
       ctrl2.Controls.Add(tbu);
```

and so on.

My question is: how do i retrieve text from those textboxes after user clicks submit button?

I've surfed around in stackoverflow, but I have yet to find the solution.

I've fiddled around a little with the following code (based on some stackoverflow topics):

```
 protected string GetTextBoxValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "";
        foreach (TextBox textBox in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            message += textBox.ID + ": " + textBox.Text + "\\n";
        }
        return message;
    }
```

and then print out values in submit_click:

```
Response.Write(GetTextBoxValues(sender, e));
```

but that doesn't give me anything

basically, i want tto read all values from each div (containing about 6 textboxes), separate the with semicolons so i could manipulate the data further

Comment: Where in the asp page life-cycle are you creating the text boxes?  They have to be created and available for the postback in order to read their values as controls.

Comment: textboxes are created in page_load. upon my searches i came accross this "postback" of which you speak, but i didnt understand it fully. Maybe you can shed some light into this?

Comment: "Postback" is one of the most important things to understand about ASP.NET if you want to do almost anything.  It is when the form is posted back to the same URL that it originated from.  Part of ASP's job during postback is to repopulate control values from the values in the http post collection.  If the control doesn't exist at that point, it won't get populated.  I'd **highly** recommend you read up more on the asp life cycle if you want to do anything serious in asp.net.

Comment: If you could show us more of the code surrounding the dynamic control creation, that would be very helpful.  Specifically, we need to see enough to know which page event (init, load, etc) that creation code is happening from, and under what conditions.

Comment: edited my post to reflect  that page_load is the event the boxes are created in. There shouldbe no further conditions on textbox creation, other than its happening 10 times and each time with according IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Controls.OfType<TextBox>` is a good approach, but it is not a recursive one. It will look at the top of the page for textboxes. You have added them to child container with the "meaningful" names `div1` and `div2`, so use this:

```
var allTextBoxes = div1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Concat(div2.Controls.OfType<TextBox>());
foreach (TextBox textBox in allTextBoxes)
{
    message += textBox.ID + ": " + textBox.Text + "\\n";
}
```

You could use a recursive method instead, but i  strongly advise against it. You might find textboxes which you don't want to include.

Note that you have to create the dynamic controls in `Page_Init` and on every postback.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, thanks. But the boxes are still returning "": page10: \npage10url: \n i think it has something to do with the postbacks mentioned in the comments of the first post

Comment: Are you recreating the textboxes on each and every postback in `Page_Load`(better `Page_Init`) as mentioned? You also have to assign the same ID's.

Comment: I will mark your answer with a tick as it helped me the most, although i substituted allTextBoxes variable with another for loop iterating over my divisors

Answer (score -1):

Most simple, though not elegant, way would be to make their ID static, then read directly from the Request.Form collection.

To make the ID static, add this:

```
tbt.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
```

Then to read the submitted values:

```
Request.Form.Keys.OfType<string>().ToList().FindAll(k => k.StartsWith("page")).ForEach(inputName =>
{
    var value = Request.Form[inputName];
    var index = Int32.Parse(inputName.Substring(4));
    //handle value...
});
```

You can easily put it into a Dictonary object as well for quick access by the index:

```
Dictionary<int, string> pageValues = new Dictionary<int, string>();
Request.Form.Keys.OfType<string>().ToList().FindAll(k => k.StartsWith("page")).ForEach(inputName =>
{
    var value = Request.Form[inputName];
    var index = Int32.Parse(inputName.Substring(4));
    pageValues.Add(index, value);
});
```